# Only consume latest item with onBackpressureLatest()

Tags: java, rx-java2

I have a producer which emits items periodically and a consumer which is sometimes quite slow. It is important that the consumer only works with recent items. I thought onBackpressureLatest() is the perfect solution for this problem. So I wrote the following test code:

```
PublishProcessor<Integer> source = PublishProcessor.create();
source
        .onBackpressureLatest()
        .observeOn(Schedulers.from(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
        .subscribe(i -> {
            System.out.println("Consume: " + i);
            Thread.sleep(100);
        });

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println("Produce: " + i);
    source.onNext(i);
}
```

I expected it to log something like:

```
Produce: 0
...
Produce: 9
Consume: 0
Consume: 9
```

Instead, I get

```
Produce: 0
...
Produce: 9
Consume: 0
Consume: 1
...
Consume: 9
```

onBackpressureLatest() and onBackpressureDrop() do both not have any effect. Only onBackpressureBuffer(i) causes an exception.

I use rxjava 2.1.9. Any ideas what the problem/my misunderstanding could be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`observeOn` has an internal buffer (default 128 elements) that will pick up all source items easily immediately, thus the `onBackpressureLatest` is always fully consumed.

**Edit:**

The smallest buffer you can create is 1 which should provide the required pattern:

```
source.onBackpressureLatest()
      .observeOn(Schedulers.from(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()), false, 1)
      .subscribe(v -> { /* ... */ });
```

(the earlier `delay` + `rebatchRequest` combination is practically equivalent to this).

Comment: Is there a way I can provide an `onDrop` method with the same functionality as `onBackpressureLatest()` + `observeOn(..., 1)`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is supposed to work but I'm not entirely sure

```
 PublishProcessor<Integer> source = PublishProcessor.create();
 source
    .onBackpressureLatest()
    .switchMap(item -> Flowable.just(item)) // <--
    .observeOn(
         Schedulers.from(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
    .subscribe(i -> {
        System.out.println("Consume: " + i);
        Thread.sleep(100);
    });
```

Comment: I don't get any output for this code. However, the accepted solution works good enough for me (although I do not find it fully satisfying).