# Skip middle elements of a BehaviousSubject while pending in an Android app

Tags: android, rx-java

I have and Android app that uses Rx-Java.
I have an screen that displays a list of models form the database
I have a filter where the user inputs a text and the results of the list are filtered.
To do so I have:

A behaviourSubject for the filter

```
BehaviorSubject<String> filterEmmiter = BehaviorSubject.create();

// When users inputs a text
filterEmmiter.onNext(newText);

// To get items
Flowable<String> filter = filterEmmiter.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST);
filter.flatMap((currentFilter)-> vacaDao.fullDataGroupedWhere(state,  stage, currentFilter));
```

Te problem is that the query is slower that the user inputing text, therefore I want that when a new key is pressed, if there are query that have not started discard them. That is the idea of the BackpressureStrategy.LATEST, but it is not working (all queries are called).

I've read in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48433244/only-consume-latest-item-with-onbackpressurelatest) that the problem is that there is a buffer on the observer, however I don't like the solution posted.

Is there anyway to solve this?

Thanks,

## Stand Alone Sample

I want the following test to print only:
D/TestTime: value processed:1
D/TestTime: value processed:10

```
    @Test
    public void someTest(){
        BehaviorSubject<Integer> filterEmmiter = BehaviorSubject.create();
        Flowable<Integer> filter = filterEmmiter.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST);
        final int maxint = 10;
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i <= maxint; i++) {
                filterEmmiter.onNext(i);
            }
        }).start();

        filter.flatMap(integer -> {
            return Flowable.fromCallable(() -> {
                longOperation();
                Log.d("TestTime", "value processed:"+integer);
                return integer;
            });
        }, false, 1, 1)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(Schedulers.from(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()), false, 1)
                .filter(value -> value==maxint).blockingFirst();
    }
```

Comment: slightly different behavior but you might be what you want anyways is to use `switchMap` instead of `flatMap`. Otherwise note the overloads of the flatMap, it also has a buffer

Comment: @Aarjav The problem of switchMap is that the queries will be called just that the results would not be used. Therefore I'm not avoiding all the queries cost and the last query will continue to take as long as the previous version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, you can use `switchMap` to cancel a previous query when there is a new filter text. In addition, you may want to wait for the user to pause typing before firing off the next query:

```java
filterEmmiter
.debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
.switchMap(currentFilter -> vacaDao.fullDataGroupedWhere(state,  stage, currentFilter))
...
```

**Edit**

If you want to limit the query execution to one, even if the user keeps typing, use the [maxConcurrency overload of `flatMap`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/Flowable.html#flatMap-io.reactivex.rxjava3.functions.Function-boolean-int-)

```java
filterEmmiter
.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
.flatMap(currentFilter -> 
     vacaDao.fullDataGroupedWhere(state,  stage, currentFilter), 
     false,   // <-------- delayErrors
     1        // <-------- maxConcurrency
)
...
```

There is also a 3rd party operator [`flatMapLatest`](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJavaExtensions#observabletransformersflatmaplatest) to accomplish this with an `Observable` directly.

**Edit 2**

From comments, you have to make your `fromCallable` async otherwise it will block the chain and backpressure will have no effect:

```java
filter.flatMap(integer -> {
            return Flowable.fromCallable(() -> {
                longOperation();
                Log.d("TestTime", "value processed:"+integer);
                return integer;
            }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()); // <---------------------------------
        }, false, 1, 1)
        .observeOn(Schedulers.from(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()), false, 1)
        .filter(value -> value==maxint).blockingFirst();
```

Comment: The problem of switchMap is that the queries will be called just that the results would not be used. Therefore I'm not avoiding all the queries cost and the last query will continue to take as long as the previous version.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you try to achieve then. Do you want to run one query at a time even though the user keeps typing more?

Comment: I don't want to call queries that will never be used. Each time the user presses a key a new query is executed (one after another). It he user presses 10 keys there will be 10 queries. What I want is that when the user presses the first key, a query is executed. When this query finishes if there is still 8 queries to do, discard them all and only execute the last one.

Comment: I've added a stand alone example

Comment: Okay, that's what the flatMap with maxConcurrency example can do. Note though that doing Thread.sleeps may not be accurate enough to get the value 1 and 10 processed only.

Comment: But its not working. All 10 items are processed. I've modified the sleep with a longOperation and not working yet.

Comment: I see. The longOperation blocks the thread where the `onBackpressureLatest` operates thus makes it ineffective. Apply `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` to that `fromCallable` and you should no longer see each item executed still.

Comment: Also tried with .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()), but does not do the trick. Still 10 logOperations executed. (example updated)

Comment: As I said, apply it to `fromCallable`, not after the `flatMap`. See updated answer.